# Is it possible to redefine subroutines to be localized for a part of the code?

Tags: perl, module, subroutine, redefine

Is it possible to redefine the `_function_used_by_exported_function` only for the `exported_function` call in the `second_routine`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; 
use strict;
use Needed::Module qw(exported_function);


sub first_routine {
    return exported_function( 2 );
}

no warnings 'redefine';

sub Needed::Module::_function_used_by_exported_function {
    return 'B';
}

sub second_routine {
    return exported_function( 5 );
}

say first_routine();
say second_routine();
```

Comment: You can do that, but it's unpleasant.  If you explain what you're using it for we can probably come up with a better way.

Comment: It would have been a little speed gain. But I don't want unpleasant code in this case so won't use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can locally redefine the `sub _function_used_by_exported_function` inside your `sub second_routine`.

```
package Foo;
use warnings; 
use strict;
use base qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(exported_function);

sub exported_function {
  print 10 ** $_[0] + _function_used_by_exported_function();
}

sub _function_used_by_exported_function {
  return 5;
}

package main;
use warnings; 
use strict;

Foo->import; # "use"

sub first_routine {
    return exported_function( 2 );
}

sub second_routine {
    no warnings 'redefine';
    local *Foo::_function_used_by_exported_function = sub { return 2 };
    return exported_function( 5 );
}

say first_routine();
say second_routine();
say first_routine();
```

I lifted the typeglob assignment inside `sub second_routine` from brian d foy's *Mastering Perl*, Chapter 10 on page 161. The sub is redefined by assigning to the typeglob, which only replaces the coderef part of it. I use [`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) to only do that inside the current block. That way, the outside world is not affected by the change, as you can see in the output.

```
1051
1000021
1051
```